# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'related_uuid' - django object filter

Tags: python, django

you need to output the queryset in html

**html**

does not output data

```
{% for related_item in related_uuid %}
       Related: {{ related_item.related_uuid }}
{% endfor %}
```

**views**

```
class OrdersHomeView(ListView):
    model = Orders
    template_name = 'orders/orders_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'orders'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        related_uuid = Clients.objects.filter(related_uuid='xxx'))
        context['related_uuid'] = related_uuid
        print('related_uuid', related_uuid.related_uuid)
        >> terminal AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'related_uuid'
        return context
```

**models**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Имя')  
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True, verbose_name='uuid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do this

the `filter` will return `queryset`. So use `get` instead of a filter.

```
context['related_uuid'] = related_uuid
print('related_uuid', related_uuid.related_uuid)  ==> this is invalid
```

if you want to view the related_uuid

try this

```
context['related_uuid'] = related_uuid
print('related_uuid', related_uuid.values_list('related_uuid'))
```